# When trying to fill our time-series data-frame, “missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames”

Tags: r

```r
for (pXm in 1:dim(dsa)[1]){
  dtf[as.character(unlist(dsa[pXm,"Product_Code"])),unlist(dsa[pXm,"timestamp"])]<- 
    unlist(dsa[pXm,"Order_Demand"])
}
```

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, as.character(unlist(dsa[pXm, "Product_Code"])),  : 
>     missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: No NA s data in my dataset. In previous time time few many data are NA s but right now nothing because i was preprocessed whole data.

Comment: Hi Wasim. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your comment should be part of your question. Without your comment, your question lacks a question. Please show us some data by using `dput(head(dsa,10))`.

Comment: thnx. i can slove this problem :)

Answer (score -1):

```
dsa$timestamp <- unlist(lapply(dates, FUN= YeMo_to_int))
dsa[is.na(dsa)] <- 0
```

The `YeMo_to_int` function may return some NA values, thus the reason this error occurs.